# Accessing protected members of klarna API

Tags: php

so i am using an API whose return is protected members.
My code :-

```
var_dump($a)
```

Gets me something like this :-

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(Klarna\XMLRPC\Address)[26]
      protected 'email' => string '' (length=0)
      protected 'telno' => string '' (length=0)
      protected 'cellno' => string '' (length=0)
      protected 'fname' => string 'Testperson-se' (length=13)
      protected 'lname' => string 'Approved' (length=8)
```

How can I access the protected members?

I tried to do it via :- `var_dump($addrs->country)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a protected method/property outside of that class. That's why is called "protected". You have to create a public getter:

```
public function getEmail() 
{
   return $this->email;
}
```

and use it as $a->getEmail(); and so on for rest of properties you need

Comment: I just checked that class, you already have that getter: https://github.com/klarna/php-xmlrpc/blob/v5.0/src/Klarna/XMLRPC/Address.php line 190. Please check documentation https://github.com/klarna/php-xmlrpc/tree/v5.0/docs/examples

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use this, I can't seem to understand it.